# Procedure called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention error occuring when trying to call a function of a ctype DLL

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

**Code:**

1. from ctypes import cdll
2. x = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\CommDLL5\COMMDLL5")
3. info = x.COMMINFO(1)

**Error:**

1. Traceback (most recent call last):
2. File "E:\Python prgm\dll_read.py", line 12, in
3. info = x.COMMINFO(1)
4. ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (4 bytes
   missing) or wrong calling convention.

**Information on that DLL:**

5. CommInfo: Returns library information.
6. SYNTAX: CommInfo(CommandCode)
7. CommandCode:

> > VB function Prototype: CommInfo (ByVal CommandCode As Long) As Long
> >     REMARKS:
> >
> > CommInfo returns a code corresponding to the CommandCode used.
> >
> > [COMMAND : (0) ]    =            [[Result] : DLL Version Number]
> >
> > [COMMAND : (1) ]    =            [[Result] : DLL Version Type (32
> >      for Windows 32-bit version of the Library)]
> >
> > [COMMAND : (2) ]    =            [[Result] : DLL Month of release]
> >
> > [COMMAND : (3) ]    =            [[Result] :  DLL Year of release]
> >
> > Please tell me how or what should be passed exactly to get the result mentioned above.

Comment: `COMMINFO` probably uses the `__stdcall` calling convention instead of `__cdecl`.  Try 'windll.LoadLibrary` instead.  You also should define `x.COMMINFO.argtypes` and `x.COMINFO.restype` for best results.  See the `ctypes` documentation.